# R: reshape data frame when one column has unequal number of entries

Tags: r, reshape

I have a data frame x with 2 character columns:

```
x <- data.frame(a = numeric(), b = I(list()))
x[1:3,"a"] = 1:3
x[[1, "b"]] <- "a, b, c"
x[[2, "b"]] <- "d, e"
x[[3, "b"]] <- "f"
x$a = as.character(x$a)
x$b = as.character(x$b)
x
str(x)
```

The entries in column b are comma-separated strings of characters.
I need to produce this data frame:

1  a

1  b

1  c

2  d

2  e

3  f

I know how to do it when I loop row by row. But is it possible to do without looping?

Thank you!

Comment: if the answers solve your problem, you can check it to indicate as correct!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out `require(splitstackshape)`?

```
> cSplit(x, "b", ",", direction = "long")

   a b
1: 1 a
2: 1 b
3: 1 c
4: 2 d
5: 2 e
6: 3 f
```

Comment: package by @anandmahto

Answer (score 0):

```
> s <- strsplit(as.character(x$b), ',')
> data.frame(value=rep(x$a, sapply(s, FUN=length)),b=unlist(s))
  value  b
1     1  a
2     1  b
3     1  c
4     2  d
5     2  e
6     3  f
```

Answer (score 0):

there you go, should be very fast:

```
library(data.table)

x <- data.table(x)
x[ ,strsplit(b, ","), by = a]
```